# Double Linked List Crashing After Appending Node

Tags: c, crash, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to achieve a double linked list using C and have encountered a crash whenever I try to append a third node to my list. I have located the line in my code in which my program crashes, but I cannot understand why since the code looks "safe". I have received no warnings or errors from the compiler. If anyone is able to explain a possible pointer error or the reason behind the crash, it would be much appreciated. Any questions or concerns related to my code will be answered as soon as I see them.

```
struct node *appendNode(struct node *headRef, unsigned short int newData) {
     struct node *newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
     newNode->data = newData;
     newNode->next = NULL;
     if(headRef == NULL) { //list is empty and returns the newNode to become the head pointer
         newNode->previous = NULL;
         return newNode;
     } else { //list is not empty and newNode is appended to end of list ----(Area of crash)----
         struct node *current = headRef;
         while(current->next != NULL) {
             current = current->next;
         }
         current->next = newNode;
         newNode->previous = current;
         return headRef;
     }       //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 };
```

The code presented above is a function that appends a new node to the list. It returns a new address or same address back when finished to update the head pointer used in 'main'. The code runs functionally whenever I append the first two nodes, but crashes whenever it tries to append a third node.

Comment: I understand the term is "Doubly-Linked List", but I accidentally referenced it as a Double Linked List. My apologies.

Comment: You can edit the question to fix the wording.

Comment: Can you share the full code triggering the error ? Valgrind can help you or gdb and step by step check what happens.

Comment: @microhex: If you want to write a comment to an answer, please place your comment in the appropriate section. The question and answer each have their own comments section. If you write a comment to an answer, the answerer will also be automatically notified of your comment. However, he won't be notified if you instead write your comment in the comments section of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of memory space you are allocating is the size **of a pointer to** a `struct node`, not the actual size of a `struct node` - which you want.

So it should be

```
struct node *newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

As a consequence of allocating insufficient memory, your program is writing outside the memory block that it allocated, which causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This means that anything can happen. For example, the program may crash immediately, not at all, or at a later time.