# Linked List multiple arrows in C

Tags: c, linked-list

A question about linked list in data structure (in C language)
let say I have 4 elements in the list and it is like
(address)[data | pointer to next block]

like this
(252) [5 | 272]--> (272)[8 |286]--> (286)[11 | 296]--> (296)[15|NULL]

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

struct node* head; //global variable
```

**Here is the question about Arrow Control**
if I want to traverse to the 4th element from the head, Can I say that like this?

(252) [5 | 272]--> (272)[8 |286]--> (286)[11 | 296]--> (296)[15|NULL]---X

```
// let's suppose I stored 1st element in a variable and already linked them together 

struct node* temp1 = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
temp1->data = 5;
temp1->next = 272;
.
.
.
```

can i say that

```
temp1->next; // value is 272
temp1->next->data; // data is 8

temp1->next->next; // value is 286
temp1->next->next->data; //data is 11

temp1->next->next->next; // value is 296
temp1->next->next->next->data; // value is 15

temp1->next->next->next->next; // value is NULL
```

Can I use multiple arrows to traverse the linked list directly instead of using loop?

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to?

Comment: Yes? If you're asking if _it's done_; it is.

Comment: I see you're saving space for a pointer, instead of the node itself! [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60821005/double-linked-list-crashing-after-appending-node/60821069#60821069) had the same problem. Read the adapted answer by Andreas.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navigational_database and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter for more general background

Answer (score 1):

You can, but only if you are certain that *all* the elements before the one you want have a valid `next` pointer, or in other words, only if you are certain that the list contains enough elements.

The reason why it's usually done in a loop is because you usually don't know how long the list is beforehand, and you need to check each element to make sure. If you don't know how many elements are in the the list, then doing `->next->next->...` directly can cause the program to dereference a `NULL` pointer, which is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're hesitating because of the chain you get. To prevent this long chaining, we use a `while`-loop, like:

```c
int main()
{
    struct node* head = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node))
    // you want to be saving space for a new struct on the heap
    // not space for a struct pointer on the heap

    // addNodeAtEnd(&head, 0);
    // addNodeAtEnd(&head, 1);
    // addNodeAtEnd(&head, 2);
    // ...

    if (head != NULL) {
        struct node* p = head;
        while (p->next != NULL) {
            p = p->next;
            ; // do something like printf(p->data)
        }
    }
}
```